# How to update alarm set on boot completed ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an alarm that let's say fire on 15:00 O'Clock. I am starting alarm on Boot completed    Listener but I want it to fire every day at 15:00. However user can modify alarm time. The problem is once I modify the alarm time it stops firing.

Following is my code:

```
public class SystemBootListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Toast.makeText(context,"SystemBootListener onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ConnectivityWatcher.class);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,0);

        long _alarm = 0;

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();

        alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(AppSettings.getAlarmHour(context)));
        int min=Integer.parseInt(AppSettings.getAlarmMin(context));
        alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);

        if(alarm.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
            _alarm = alarm.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
        else
            _alarm = alarm.getTimeInMillis();  

        // Trigger every 10 seconds
        // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm, 5*1000, pending);
      }


 public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        //Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Set by Activity"+       Integer.parseInt(AppSettings.getAlarmHour(context)) + ":"+   Integer.parseInt(AppSettings.getAlarmMin(context)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConnectivityWatcher.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,0);

        long _alarm = 0;

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();

        alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(AppSettings.getAlarmHour(context)));
        int min=Integer.parseInt(AppSettings.getAlarmMin(context));
        alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);

        if(alarm.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
            _alarm = alarm.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);

        else
            _alarm = alarm.getTimeInMillis();  
        // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,5*1000, pi);
        //service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),  , pi); 


        Toast.makeText(context,alarm.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+" :"+alarm.get(Calendar.MINUTE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConnectivityWatcher.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);

    }

    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConnectivityWatcher.class);
        //intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
    }

}
```

Comment: Whenever you want to modify alarm then simply cancel the first and set new one, very simple funda.

Comment: in the above code alarm fires once the device is booted then after it won't. Why this behaviour?

Comment: because you are using `setInexactRepeating()` method. You should use `setRepeating()` see this [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)'s RTC Example Session

Comment: but in DOC it specifies that Use setInexactRepeating() instead of setRepeating()

Comment: have you read this line `Wake up the device to fire the alarm at approximately 2:00 p.m., and repeat once a day at the same time:` on that page ?

Comment: I got it.It is saying if i use setInexactRepeating() ,then i can't use custom interval. Thanks for info

Comment: You welcome.....Should I post my comment as answer ?

Comment: Hi I tried...But no luck. Once the device is booted it fires only once but not on time say i set 12:50 and interval is 5 sec, when device time is 12:45. when device booted it fires at 12:48 then no more fires. which is unaccepted.

Comment: on which devoice you are testing this code ? and Android version.